# Ionic 3.20.0 app unresponsive (scrolling and clicking does not work)

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, angular5, angularfire2

Hey so I'm working on a modified version of the tabs starter app and my app just started to be unresponsive in terms of scrolling and clicking. Only the tabs button works which switches the pages. Nothing else. I'll post the code below, does anyone have any ideas?

app.html

```
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

app.component.ts

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, Nav } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { AboutPage } from '../pages/about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';
import { VendorPage } from '../pages/vendor/vendor';
import { TipsPage } from '../pages/tips/tips';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  rootPage:any = TabsPage;

  pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;

  constructor(public platform: Platform,
              public statusBar: StatusBar,
              public splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    this.initializeApp();

    // used for an example of ngFor and navigation
    this.pages = [
      { title: 'Home', component: HomePage },
      { title: 'About', component: AboutPage },
      { title: 'Contact', component: ContactPage },
      { title: 'Vendors', component: VendorPage },
      { title: 'Tips', component: TipsPage }
    ];
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available. Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }

  openPage(page) {
    // Reset the content nav to have just this page
    // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
  }

}
```

home.ts

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
import { Device } from '@ionic-native/device';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AuthService } from '../../app/core/auth.service';

declare var google: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  currentEvents;
  user: Observable<firebase.User>;

  @ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
  map: any;
  markers = [];
  ref = firebase.database().ref('geolocations/');

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public platform: Platform,
              private geolocation: Geolocation,
              private device: Device,
              private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
              private authService: AuthService) {

    platform.ready().then(() => {
      //this.initMap();
    });

    this.ref.on('value', resp => {
      this.deleteMarkers();
      snapshotToArray(resp).forEach(data => {
        if(data.uuid !== this.device.uuid) {
          let image = 'assets/imgs/green-bike.png';
          let updatelocation = new google.maps.LatLng(data.latitude,data.longitude);
          this.addMarker(updatelocation,image);
          this.setMapOnAll(this.map);
        } else {
          let image = 'assets/imgs/blue-bike.png';
          let updatelocation = new google.maps.LatLng(data.latitude,data.longitude);
          this.addMarker(updatelocation,image);
          this.setMapOnAll(this.map);
        }
      });
    });

    this.currentEvents = [
      {
        year: 2018,
        month: 4,
        date: 22
      },
      {
        year: 2018,
        month: 6,
        date: 16
      }
    ];
  }

  onDaySelect(ev) {

  }

  onMonthSelect(ev) {
    
  }

  initMap() {
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition({ maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true }).then((resp) => {
        let mylocation = new google.maps.LatLng(resp.coords.latitude,resp.coords.longitude);
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, {
          zoom: 15,
          center: mylocation
        });
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error getting location ' + error);
      });
      let watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition();
      watch.subscribe((data) => {
        this.deleteMarkers();
        //this.updateGeolocation(this.device.uuid, data.coords.latitude,data.coords.longitude);
        let updatelocation = new google.maps.LatLng(data.coords.latitude,data.coords.longitude);
        let image = 'assets/imgs/blue-bike.png';
        this.addMarker(updatelocation,image);
        this.setMapOnAll(this.map);
      });
  }

  addMarker(location, image) {
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: this.map,
      icon: image
    });
    this.markers.push(marker);
  }

  setMapOnAll(map) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.markers.length; i++) {
      this.markers[i].setMap(map);
    }
  }

  clearMarkers() {
    this.setMapOnAll(null);
  }

  deleteMarkers() {
    this.clearMarkers();
    this.markers = [];
  }

  updateGeolocation(uuid, lat, lng) {
    if(localStorage.getItem('mykey')) {
      firebase.database().ref('geolocations/'+localStorage.getItem('mykey')).set({
        uuid: uuid,
        latitude: lat,
        longitude: lng
      });
    } else {
      let newData = this.ref.push();
      newData.set({
        uuid: uuid,
        latitude: lat,
        longitude: lng
      });
      localStorage.setItem('mykey', newData.key);
    }
  }

}

export const snapshotToArray = snapshot => {
    let returnArr = [];

    snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
        let item = childSnapshot.val();
        item.key = childSnapshot.key;
        returnArr.push(item);
    });

    return returnArr;
};
```

Not sure if something in my app.module.ts can cause this?

Comment: Can we see the code from *before* you broke everything?

Comment: I'll have to look through git. I found the issue though! It's ion-tabs but I don't know how to fix it. If i set the rootPage to HomePage it works fine. But when I set it to the tabsPage it doesn't.